Путаюсь в доме?
Дом слишком большой, до сих пор иногда в нём путаюсь
Я знаю, что по смыслу правильнее использовать слово "заблудиться", но у него нет подходящей формы, которая хорошо бы здесь звучала.
Вопрос: можно ли так сказать или всё же лучше полностью переработать предложение?

могу заблудиться, путаю расположение комнат.

Дом слишком огромный, до сих пор не могу сразу найти нужной комнаты, путаюсь.

Переработать предложение не проблема, вопрос был о конкретном выражении.

Вот что имеется в словаре многих выражений:
пу́таться
8) разг. Бродить, блуждать в поисках дороги, нужного направления.
Пу́таться в улицах. Пу́таться в незнакомом городе.
Дом слишком большой, до сих пор иногда в нём путаюсь (= плутаю).
Думаю, что так можно выразиться в разговорном стиле (точку в конце предложения не забываем).
Примеры из Нацкорпуса
Ночью я просыпаюсь, и я путаюсь в своей комнате, ибо я забываю теперешнюю мою комнату и помню ту каморку, которая была у меня на Чермозе (Б. А. Пильняк. Иван Москва).
Вроде бы ищу и путаюсь в Москве, обликом, однако, шибко смахивающей на город Чусовой с его грязными улочками и переулками, по окраинам превращенными в помойки и свалки (Виктор Астафьев. Веселый солдат (1987-1997)).
Я спросила, что он делает в Мидвинтере, а он скорчил недовольную физиономию и сказал, что его маму и папу пригласили в гости. Он не видел их с самого приезда и даже не знает, где их комната. (Значит, не я одна путаюсь в этих коридорах.) (Джулия Ли. Нэнси Паркер и мертвец в библиотеке).

"Вроде бы ищу и путаюсь в Москве..." - так-то тоже странно звучит)

О грамматике предложения

Большой толковый словарь

ПУТАТЬ, -аю, -аешь; нсв. 10. Разг. Лишать ясности, чёткости, логичности; делать беспорядочным, сбивчивым; путаться в чём-л. Начинает отвечать урок и путает. Путать божий дар с яичницей (см. Божий). Путаться, -ается; страд. (1-6 зн.).

Путаться – возвратный залог.  В этом случае  субъект взаимодействует с объектом, действие частично от объекта переходит на субъект.

3.Объект здесь обозначен  формой в доме. Но в словаре указан именно предмет  (в чем?), а не где? Обычно говорят: путаюсь (в чем?) в словах, в мыслях и т. д. Нацкорус.

Поэтому это разговорный вариант, отчасти метафорический. Другими словами, объектом является сам дом.  Тем не менее вариант используется в речи, хотя и может показаться странным.


Дом просто не объект, то есть снаружи он объект, а внутри не совсем. Путаюсь в домах - нормально звучит, а путаюсь в доме - нет. Можно кстати путаюсь в своём доме - так лучше. Может, потому что в доме - это где?, а не в чём?.

Да, вы правы: путаюсь в  домах – нормально, здесь  дома – объекты. А в доме – внутри объекта. Я путаюсь, когда нахожусь в доме.  Объекта уже нет.

Да, забавное слово, снаружи одно - а внутри другое) - как не запутаться?

Ну да.  Когда на улице, путаешься в домах (никак свой не найдешь).  Когда в доме, путаешься в комнатах. Когда на кухне,  путаешься в кастрюлях  и т.д
